# Accessing context values from within context file

Tags: reactjs, authentication, state

I'm having some issue with my context file. I have a file called "auth-state" that I use to manage application wide authentication state. It initializes a react context object, and has several helper functions defined that help manage things like logging out, verifying user authentication tokens, and logging in. Excluding a lot of the helper functions, it looks like this:

```
const noUserObj = {
  userName: "Anonymous",
  isLoggedIn: false,
  authToken: "-",
  projList: null,
  attemptLogIn: () => {},
  userLogout: () => {}
}

const AuthState = React.createContext(noUserObj);

const AuthStateProvider = (props) => {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthState);
  let existingToken;

  if(localStorage.getItem("token")) { 
    existingToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  } else {
    existingToken = "-"
  }

  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(noUserObj);

   return (
      <AuthState.Provider
        value={{
          userName: user.userName,
          isLoggedIn: user.isLoggedIn,
          authToken: user.authToken,
          projList: user.projList,
          attemptLogin: attemptLoginWithAxios,
          userLogout: logoutWithAxios
      }}    
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthState.Provider>
  )
}

export {AuthStateProvider};
export default AuthState
```

I use a state variable to manage the actual context values and then pass the state variable to the context providers "value" prop. I know you can't see it here, but whenever one of the helper functions log in or out, they update the "user" state variable, and this in turn updates the context values. From my understanding this is relatively standard practice. My issue is that when trying to access the context values from within the auth-state context file itself, I always get outdated or "default" states.

This is especially confusing because when I use the react-dev tools in the chrome browser to look at the values currently saved in the auth-provider, everything looks right. I can see the values update as I login/out, and watch it function as intended. But whenever I try to access the context values from within auth-state (whether that be by using useContext(authState) or by accessing the "user" state variable itself) I only ever get the default object you see declared at the top of the authState file (noUserObj).

This is an issue because one of those helper functions I mentioned earlier (one that logs users out) requires the users authtoken to be able to log them out. And I defined this helper function inside the auth-state file explicitly because it would have easy access to all auth related variables it needed. But everytime I try to access the state variable or the context itself I only get default. I'll even run it in debug mode, pause the execution right before "logging out" runs, and see that the context variable is properly updated, but the helper function only gets default values.

I don't know what the heck is happening, but right now I'm just working around it by passing the the helper functions tokens from outside the file, wherever I actually call them. (this is even weirder because I get these tokens FROM THE AUTH-CONTEXT, its just for some reason when I use useContext(auth-state) outside of the auth-state file itself, everything works fine.) Whatever the case, I'm sure I'm just overlooking something small. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You can't `const authCtx = useContext(AuthState);` In the same component that renders the provider. AuthState context is only defined BELOW the provider in the react tree. (assuming there is only one provider)

Comment: @nlta is correct. This use case begs for something like react-redux.

Comment: Its great you wrote in such detail , buit it would be a lot more helpful to describe the problem in shorter sentences and best share with us some code using codsandbox f.e, so we can try to better help you.

Comment: Its great you wrote in such detail , buit it would be a lot more helpful to describe the problem in shorter sentences and best share with us some code using codsandbox f.e, so we can try to better help you.